# Vue js, Axios, Oracle. How can i load ref cursor from db with one blob field?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, blob, devextreme

I have a task. I need load records from Oracle to web with vue js with using axios. I have in db a procedure with out parameter type sys refcursor. In cursor there are records with three fields, two fields are varchar, and one field is blob. I do get request over axios and get data, then this data link to grid from DevExtreme. But as a result I see in a table only varchar values and blob is not showing. Code here, I just began learn Web, that's why it can be bad)

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <DxDataGrid
      id="gridContainer"
      :data-source="gridData"
      :show-borders="true"
    >
      <DxColumn
        :width="100"
        data-field="CODE"
      />
      <DxColumn
        :width="215"
        data-field="PREVIEW_IMAGE"
        cell-template="cellTemplate"
      />
      <DxColumn
        :width="200"
        data-field="FILE_NAME"
      />
      <template #cellTemplate="{ data }">
        <img :src="data.value">
      </template>
    </DxDataGrid>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from "axios";
  import { DxButton } from "devextreme-vue/button";
  import { DxDataGrid, DxColumn } from "devextreme-vue/data-grid";

  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    props: {
      msg: String
    },
    components: {
      DxButton,
      DxDataGrid,
      DxColumn
    },
    data() {      
      return {
        gridData: []
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      axios.get("/api/mo_web_api/item_list_for_grid")
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data.o_item_list);
          this.gridData = response.data.o_item_list;
        })
    }
  }
</script>
```